# MERGE table using old value + new value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following tables:

Table1:

```
Id |   ClientId  |   Amount
------------------------------
1  |   100       |   
2  |   130       |   
..
9  |   280       |
```

Table2: source table

```
Id |  CashId  |  Price  |  Tax
-----------------------------
1  |    1     |   550   |  120
2  |    1     |   100   |   30
3  |    2     |   320   |   50
4  |    3     |   360   |  100
next data loads
5  |    1     |   80    |   20
6  |    2     |   20    |    9
7  |    4     |   190   |   80
```

etc.
which is aggregating to tmp table:

Table3 (tmp):

```
Id |  CashId  |  Total_Sum
-----------------------------
1  |    1     |   800
2  |    2     |   370   
3  |    3     |   460   

next data loads
1  |    1     |   100
2  |    2     |   29
3  |    4     |   270
```

Table2 is incremental loading, for each CashId in the table cash deposit can occur a few times. For first loading are 2 cash deposit for CashId=1. For second loading is 1 cash deposit for CashId=1 but this loading came out next day.

I would like to check if next loading comes new cash deposit. The amount column from Table1 consist of sum data from Price and Tax from Table2 for each CashId.

Table1.Id = Table2.CashId

How should look Table1 after 1st loading:

```
Id |   ClientId  |   Amount
------------------------------
1  |   100       |   800
2  |   130       |   370
...
```

After 2nd loading data:

```
Id |   ClientId  |   Amount
------------------------------
1  |   100       |   800 + 100 = 900
2  |   130       |   370 + 29 = 399
...
```

I thought to use statement like this:

```
MERGE INTO Table1 trg
USING (SELECT * FROM Table3) cash
    ON trg.Id = cash.CashId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET trg.Amount = 'trg.Amount + new Total_Sum'
```

I need to add new Total_Sum from new loading to existed data in Amount column in Table1. When come new data and I run MERGE statement, Total_Sum sould be add to existed value in Amount column but when data come first time should be replace null value in Amount column.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have the syntax:

```
MERGE INTO Table1 trg
USING (SELECT * FROM Table3) cash
    ON trg.Id = cash.CashId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET trg.Amount = trg.Amount + cash.Total_Sum;
```

You might want to modify this to:

```
MERGE INTO Table1 trg
USING (SELECT cashid, sum(Total_Sum) as Total_Sum
       FROM Table3
       GROUP BY cashid
      ) cash
    ON trg.Id = cash.CashId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET trg.Amount = trg.Amount + cash.Total_Sum;
```

This should handle duplicate values in `Table3`.

Comment: I tried this way and i'm getting error: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"  A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml  activity or a non-deterministic where clause.

Comment: @Merix - you've said it's aggregated, but are you sure you don't have duplicate CashId values in table3?